# Not quite Saturated

Tags: word, wordplay, rebus, metapuzzles

The answer to this Puzzle would be a single word.

## 1. **Dancing Descent**

[image]

## 2. **Cryptic Rebuses for another idea?**

[image]

## 3. **Fish type, maybe?**

Crustacean, few, Culture, finest(4,1) or (1,4)
Dear, spoken, tanks, besides (2,1) or (1,2)
Diane, Grey, miss, All (3,1) or (1,3)
Smooch, lightbulb, risque, tells (3,4) or (4,3)

## 4. **Missing a Bite.**

In same side or in replacing five with 100 in mask. (7)
A Real follows endless spy. Short moment with tailless bird (5)
Earlier m instead of p in bear. Rock music follows Public Relations with unending alarm (8)

## 5. **Wordsearch or Wordmake?**

[image]

Periodic Hints will be given. Here's the first one.

> 4 doesn't have *valid* cryptic clues. And it's a tad indirect.
>  Second hint is written above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### 1.

> This is the Dancing Men cipher, and it says `ANCESTRAL FIFTY IN ODD HALF ELAPSE SIX`: that's a cryptic clue for **LINEAL** (L + IN + EAL*, anagram of the first half of ELAPSE).

### 2.

> These rebuses are:
>  1. SONG (S on G)
>  2. SPACE (Sp3000, minus 3000 (Roman numerals), plus ACE)
>  3. DEATH (D + EA(-r)TH - thanks, Gareth!)
>  4. BOARD (B + OAR + D)
>  5. CHECK
>
>  Read down the diagonal to get **SPARK**.

### 3.

> These are all clues to word squares:
>
>  `CRAB / RARE / ARTS / BEST -->`**`B`**
>  `LOVE / ORAL / VATS / ELSE -->`**`O`**
>  `LANE / AREA / NEAR / EARS -->`**`N`** *(solved by feelinferrety)*
>  `KISS / IDEA / SEXY / SAYS -->`**`Y`**

## 4.

> These are all "double-wordplay cryptic clues" - that is, cryptic-style clues where instead of the definition, we get more wordplay. As detailed in feelinferrety's answer, we get INCISOR, MOLAR, PREMOLAR (all types of teeth), so the answer is **CANINE**.

## 5.

> NATO phonetic alphabet letters with their first letters missing are hidden here. We have PAPA, OSCAR, ROMEO, ECHO, and SIERRA, making **PORES**.
>
>  Extra letters also spell PORES, with an extra Z.
>  `---OE`
>  `P----`
>  `----S`
>  `---ZR`
>  `-----`

## Meta

> As hinted by "periodic hints", each word can be decomposed into elements on the periodic table.
>
>  - Li-Ne-Al
>  - S-P-Ar-K
>  - B-O-N-Y
>  - Ca-Ni-Ne
>  - Po-Re-S
>
>  In each word, all elements are in the same row (the same "period") - *except* for the last one. Those last elements spell **Alkynes**, a type of chemical that is "not quite saturated", as the title suggests.

Comment: I think 2.3 may be meant to be DEATH (perhaps the "definition part" is a person being shot by a laser beam? or a cactus in Death Valley? it's hard to tell). This would put an A in the place where you want one.

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer filling in the gaps in the existing primary answer.

## 3. Fish type, maybe?

- Diane, Grey, miss, All (3,1) or (1,3)

  > LANE, AREA, NEAR, EARS = **N**
- Final Answer:

  > **BONY**

## 4. Missing a Bite.

- *In same side or in replacing five with 100 in mask. (7)*

  > **INCISOR** = IN + CIS + OR / IN + [V->C]ISOR
- *A Real follows endless spy. Short moment with tailless bird (5)*

  > **MOLAR** = MOL[E] + A R / MO + LAR[K]
- *Earlier m instead of p in bear. Rock music follows Public Relations with unending alarm (8)*

  > **PREMOLAR** = PRE + [P->M]OLAR / PR + EMO + [A]LAR[M]
- And the missing one (final answer)?

  > **CANINE**